# Inline editing with jqgrid. I'm stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jqgrid, jquery-events

Here is my grid:

```
$("#list2").jqGrid({ 
    url:baseURL + 'contactManager/contactActivity/getActivity/' + contactsID + '/1', 
    datatype: "json", 
    colNames:['Type','Scheduled', 'Created', 'Comp','Description','Assigned To'], 
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'type',index:'type', width:55}, 
        {name:'scheduledDate',index:'scheduledDate', width:90}, 
        {name:'createdDate',index:'createdDate', width:100},
        {name:'completed',index:'completed', width:80, align:"center", sortable:true, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}, editable: true, edittype:"checkbox"},
        {name:'description',index:'description', width:80,align:"right"}, 
        {name:'assignedID',index:'assignedID', width:150, sortable:false} 
    ], 
    rowNum:10, 
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2', 
    sortname: 'type', 
    viewrecords: true, 
    sortorder: "desc", 
    caption:"Completed" });
```

I have a checkbox with the index name "completed."  I am trying to run an ajax call when this input is edited.  I cannot get anything to fire when I touch this checkbox, not even an alert.  I have tried working through the example on this page http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing  but nothing is working.  Can someone help me create a simple event handler for the checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$("#list2").jqGrid({ 
    url:baseURL + 'contactManager/contactActivity/getActivity/' + contactsID + '/1', 
    datatype: "json", 
    colNames:['Type','Scheduled', 'Created', 'Comp','Description','Assigned To'], 
    colModel:[ 
        {name:'type',index:'type', width:55}, 
        {name:'scheduledDate',index:'scheduledDate', width:90}, 
        {name:'createdDate',index:'createdDate', width:100},
        {name:'completed',index:'completed', width:80, align:"center", sortable:true, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}, editable: true, edittype:"checkbox"},
        {name:'description',index:'description', width:80,align:"right"}, 
        {name:'assignedID',index:'assignedID', width:150, sortable:false} 
    ], 
    rowNum:10, 
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#pager2', 
    sortname: 'type', 
    viewrecords: true, 
    sortorder: "desc", 
    caption:"Completed"
})
.find('input[name=completed]').bind('onchange', function() {alert('clicked')});
```

Comment: look at the documentation.. its funky.  i guess i could try cheesing it and just trying to find the input using jquery the way you are doing.

Comment: i will give this to you because it is a valid solution for me even though it is not really the way they do it in the documentation.

Comment: I did check it out and I didn't see anything that would bind directly to checkbox elements. There seem to be events for cell and row selections and such, though...

Comment: gahh

look how the guy does it here..  this doesnt seem to work for me:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109754/jqgrid-reload-grid-after-successfull-inline-update-inline-creation-of-record

Comment: Do you mean you can't get an event to fire with onSelectRow when you select a row? That seems to be a different issue from the checkbox. If so, that could be worth a new question. If not, I'll help however I can!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a custom formatter to bind a function to the checkbox.  Here are some snippets from my project where I used this method to send an ajax call to the database when the checkbox is clicked.

Checkbox column definition:

```
{ name: 'CoreClient', index: 'CoreClient', editable: true, align: 'center', edittype: 'checkbox', formatter: checkboxFormatter, editoptions: { value: "Y:N" }, formatoptions: { disabled: false }, sortable: true}
```

Custom formatter function:

```
//checkboxFormatter to wire onclick event of checkbox 
  function checkboxFormatter(cval, opts, rowObj) { 
      cval = cval + ""; cval = cval.toLowerCase(); 
      var bchk = cval.search(/(false|0|no|off|n)/i) < 0 ? "checked=\"checked\"" : ""; 
      return "<input type='checkbox' onclick=\"ajaxSaveParent('" + opts.rowId + "', this);\" " + bchk + " value='" + cval + "' offval='no' />"; 
  }
```

And lastly the function containing the ajax call:

```
 function ajaxSaveParent(rowid, curCheckbox) {
        var val = curCheckbox.checked ? "Y" : "N";

        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "DataService.asmx/Update",
          data: { id: rowid, yesno: val },
          success: function (data, textStatus) {
              if (textStatus == "success") {
                  //success code here
              }
          },
          error: function (data, textStatus) { //error code here }
      });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom formatter,

Add a Class to yout check box

Bind change Event on document to class

```
    jQuery(document).on("change", ".YourCheckBoxClass", function () {
    DoSomeThing(this);
});
```

In Your fomatter you can add attribute like Id, colName etc and can be retireved into DoSomeThing

Change `{name:'completed',index:'completed', width:80, align:"center", sortable:true, formatter: "checkbox", formatoptions: {disabled : false}`
to

```
{name:'completed',index:'completed', width:80, align:"center", sortable:true, formatter: Mycheckbox}
```

`function Mycheckbox(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" class="YourClass" id=cb'+rowObject['rowId']+ >';
}`